# Redirection using .htaccess not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to set up redirections on my wordpress website. I need to redirect all links like 
https://example.com/show/conf/125 
to 
https://sub.example.com/show/conf/125; where 125 is parameter, it can be 2460 or sometimes something like "125/?" or others. Here is what I do:

```
Redirect 301 /show/config(.*)$ 
https://sub.example.com/show/conf/$1
```

but this is not working, i get 404 (that is normal). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you added https://sub.example.com subdomain in the domains?

Comment: the subdomains exist. Also I  write the rule exactly like i put it here. but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive simply takes a path and redirects to a url. If you want to use regex you probably want `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/show/config(.*)$ https://sub.example.com/show/conf/$1
```